# Возвращаемое значение пропущено: "strcmp"

Tags: c++, классы

У меня есть класс DVDdrive. В этом классе есть конструктор с параметрами. В теле конструктора лежит 3 strcmp. Там 3 предупреждения: Возвращаемое значение пропущено: "strcmp". Если попробовать запустить, то мне вернется в последние 3 параметра pc "Sony" с кучей символов "М", вместо того, что прописано по коду ("LG", "USB 2.0", "24x/24x/24x").
Хотя, вот, работаю с массивом чаров в соседних классах - и там все работает..
Не могу понять логику. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// это омй класс
class DVDdrive {
private: 
    char manufacturer[20];
    char interfce[20];
    char speed_formula[20];
public:
    DVDdrive(const char* manu, const char* inte, const char* sf) {
        strcmp(manufacturer, manu);
        strcmp(interfce, inte);
        strcmp(speed_formula, sf);
    }
    void show_DVDdrive(void);
};
void DVDdrive::show_DVDdrive(void) {
    cout << "Производитель -->> " << manufacturer << endl;
    cout << "Интерфейс -->> " << interfce << endl;
    cout << "Скоростная формула -->> " << speed_formula << endl;
}

// это тоже мой класс
class videocard {
private:
    int GPU;
    int MemorySize;
    char CoolingSystem[20];
public:
    videocard(int g, int ms, const char* cs) {
        GPU = g;
        MemorySize = ms;
        strcpy(CoolingSystem, cs);
    }
    void show_videocard(void);
};
void videocard::show_videocard(void) {
    cout << "Частота GPU -->> " << GPU << endl;
    cout << "Система охлаждения -->> " << CoolingSystem << endl;
    cout << "Объем памяти -->> " << MemorySize << " Гб" << endl;
}


class screen {
public:
    screen(const char* t, long c, int x, int y) { //
        strcpy(type, t);
        colors = c;
        x_resolution = x;
        y_resolution = y;
    }
    void show_screen(void);
private:
    char type[30];
    long colors;
    int x_resolution;
    int y_resolution;
};
void screen::show_screen(void) {
    cout << "Тип экрана: " << type << endl;
    cout << "Количество цветов: " << colors << endl;
    cout << "Распределительная способность: " << x_resolution << " x " << y_resolution << " y " << endl;
}


class mother_board {
public: 
    mother_board(int p, int s, int r) {
        processor = p;
        speed = s;
        RAM = r;
    }
    void show_mother_board();
private:
    int processor;
    int speed;
    int RAM;
};
void mother_board::show_mother_board(void) {
    cout << "Процессор: " << processor << endl;
    cout << "Частота: " << speed << endl;
    cout << "ОЗУ: " << RAM << " Мб" << endl;
}


class computer : public screen, public mother_board, public videocard, public DVDdrive {
public: 
    computer(const char* n, int h, float f, const char* s, long c, int x, int y, int p, int sp, int r, int g, int ms, const char* cs, const char* manu, const char* inte, const char* sf) : screen(s, c, x, y), mother_board(p, sp, r), videocard(g, ms, cs), DVDdrive(manu, inte, sf) {
        strcpy(name, n);
        hard_disc = h;
        floppy = f;
    }
    void show_computer(void);
private:
    char name[50];
    int hard_disc;
    float floppy;
};
void computer::show_computer(void) {
    cout << "Тип компьютера: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Жесткий диск: " << hard_disc << " Мб" << endl;
    cout << "Дискета: " << floppy << " Мб" << endl;
    show_mother_board();
    show_screen();
    cout << "\nИнформация, которую я добавляю в класс computer (методичка) со своего класса videocard::::\n";
    show_videocard();
    cout << "\nИнформация, которую я добавляю в класс computer (методичка) со своего класса DVDdrive::::\n";
    show_DVDdrive();
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    computer pc("Sony", 1024, 1.44, "SVGA", 64000000, 780, 1024, 686, 66, 1024, 255, 8, "активная", "LG", "USB 2.0", "24x/24x/24x");

    pc.show_computer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: думаю, ты перепутал `strcmp()` и `strcpy()`, об этом компилятор заботливо и напоминает... и , на всякий, используй сразу `strncpy()`...

Comment: О Господи, да, Вы правы.
Тупейшая ошибка. Мне стыдно. Спасибо =)